# Mail server user mail rules

Tags: email, debian, postfix-mta

How can I make my **Postfix** server running on **Debian** 6 to **sort emails** by **user set rules**? I mean user rules like you have in e.g. Outlook or Gmail.

Some "pseaudocode" to show how I meant it ...

```
IF SENT TO '*@test.com' INSERT INTO FOLDER 'TestCom'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to do it would be to setup Dovecot to do local deliveries and then use Sieve rules to dispatch emails to different IMAP folders. See this [example](http://koansys.com/tech/sieve-server-side-mail-filtering-with-postfix-dovecot)

```
require ["fileinto", "regex" ];

if header :contains "List-ID" "ip@v2.listbox.com"                               { fileinto "INBOX.list.ip"; stop; }
if header :contains "List-Post" "<mailto:gnu.emacs.gnus@googlegroups.com>"      { fileinto "INBOX.list.gnu-emacs-gnus"; stop;}

if address :is "sender" "repoze-dev-bounces@lists.repoze.org"           { fileinto "INBOX.list.repoze-dev"; stop; }
if address :is "sender" "owner-freebsd-net@freebsd.org"                 { fileinto "INBOX.list.freebsd-net"; stop; }

if anyof (
   address :is "from" "support@myclient.com",
   address :is "from" "x@mail.myclient.com",
   address :is "from" "root@myclient.com")                                { fileinto "INBOX.in.myclient.zw"; stop; }
```

Answer (score 2):

Note that what you are looking for is an *MDA* a.k.a. **Mail Delivery Agent**. An *MDA* is an intermediary between an *MTA* (e.g. Postfix) and an *MUA* (e.g. Thunderbird, MS Outlook) and is optional, it is not installed or used in most environments. **Postfix** is an *MTA* a.k.a. **Mail Transfer Agent**. It is not generally the *MTA*'s job to filter out user email based on various different needs. It is the *MDA*'s job to do so. It takes email messages received by the *MTA* - mail server - and delivering them to user accounts.

To actually deliver the mails to end users' mailboxes, I recommend using *[Procmail](http://www.procmail.org/)* for you. It can be used to sort incoming emails into separate files/folders. It is versatile, robust and comes with complex regular expression support and it can work together with SpamAssassin, a powerful spam filtering program. Users can place a `.procmailrc` in their HOME directories to further adjust incoming email delivery. For example, take a look at the following code snippet in your `.procmailrc`:

```
:0:
* ^Subject: pr.*mail
procmail-mail
```

What the above does that anything that begins with the "pr" in the Subject and contains the string "mail" followed after, that email to be saved in the folder called *procmail-mail/*.

The two most commonly used *MDAs* are Procmail and Fetchmail. Ubuntu 13.04, for example, supports Procmail and Dovecot. Sieve, on the other hand, as suggested above is a mail filtering language that is not tied to any OS or architecture.